# SQL Server Multiple JOINS with Table Value Function - query never ends

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, join

I have a query with 4 joins using a table value function to get the data and when I execute it the query never ends.

Issue Details

Table valued function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetIndicator] 
(     
      @indicator varchar(50),
      @refDate datetime
)
RETURNS 
TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT
        T1.Id 
        , T1.ColINT_1
        , T1.ColNVARCHAR_1 collate DATABASE_DEFAULT as ColNVARCHAR_1 
        , T1.ColNVARCHAR_2 
        , T1.ColSMALLDATETIME_1
        , T1.ColDECIMAL_1
        , T1.ColDECIMAL_1

    FROM TABLE2 T2
    JOIN TABLE3 T3
    ON T2.COLFKT3 = T3.Id
        AND T3.ReferenceDate = @RefDate
        AND T3.State != 'Deleted'
    JOIN TABLE4 T4
        ON T2.COLFKT4 = T4.Id AND T4.Name=@indicator
    JOIN TABLE1 T1
        ON T2.COLFKT1=T1.Id
```

Query:

```
DECLARE @RefDate datetime
SET @RefDate = '30 April 2014 23:59:59'

SELECT DISTINCT OTHERTABLE.Id As Id
    FROM 
            GetIndicator('ID#1_0#INDICATOR_X',@RefDate) AS OTHERTABLE
        JOIN GetIndicator('ID#1_0#INDICATOR_Y',@RefDate) AS YTABLE  
            ON OTHERTABLE.SomeId=YTABLE.SomeId
            AND OTHERTABLE.DateOfEntry=YTABLE.DateOfEntry
        JOIN GetIndicator('ID#1_0#INDICATOR_Z',@RefDate) AS ZTABLE
            ON OTHERTABLE.SomeId=ZTABLE.SomeId
            AND OTHERTABLE.DateOfEntry=ZTABLE.DateOfEntry
        JOIN GetIndicator('ID#1_0#INDICATOR_W',@RefDate) AS WTABLE 
            ON OTHERTABLE.SomeId=WTABLE.SomeId
            AND OTHERTABLE.DateOfEntry=WTABLE.DateOfEntry
        JOIN GetIndicator('ID#1_0#INDICATOR_A',@RefDate) AS ATABLE  
            ON OTHERTABLE.SomeId=ATABLE.SomeId
            AND OTHERTABLE.DateOfEntry=ATABLE.DateOfEntry
```

Other details:

- SQL server version: 2008 R2
- If I execute the table function code outside the query, with the same args, the execution time is less the 1s.
- Each table function call return between 250 and 500 rows.

Comment: If you replace the TVF code in the query with copies of the code from inside the TVF does it run?

Comment: Perhaps the query is experiencing blocking - you can look at `sys.dm_exec_requests` for the SPID where your query is executing to see if `blocking_session_id` contains a session id.

Comment: @Max Vernon If I replace the TVF with a copy of the code the result is the same. Regarding the locks I used the sp_WhoIsActive to analyse the query execution and i did not detect any lock.

Comment: What does the execution plan look like?  Analyze it with SQL Sentry Plan Explorer.  http://www.sqlsentry.com/products/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view

Comment: @jdcorr -- Why do you have to use this function? Why can't you just add a WHERE clause `WHERE T4.Name IN (<LIST OF INDICATORS>)` and drop the date variable `T3.ReferenceDate = '20140430T23:59:59'`? Why do you have to use 4 joins? What am I missing here?

Comment: @DenisT The result will be different with your suggestion. With JOINs you only get results if the record have all the indicators, with your solution I will get results where the record have at least one of the indicators.

Comment: @MaxVernon According the query plan the major cost of the operation is in a "Index Seek (NonClustered)" [Table2].[IX_ID_COLFKT3]- 57% (the query runs for about 3-4 hours).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the function to a non-inline table value function, with a clustered index. This will store the tvf's result set in an internal temp table, which may help you. A draft of what I mean:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetIndicator] 
(     
  @indicator varchar(50),
  @refDate datetime
)
RETURNS @out TABLE (
    Id int NOT NULL,
    ColINT_1 int NOT NULL,
    -- ... and so on
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
)
AS

BEGIN;

    INSERT INTO @out
    SELECT
    T1.Id 
    , T1.ColINT_1
    , T1.ColNVARCHAR_1 collate DATABASE_DEFAULT as ColNVARCHAR_1 
    , T1.ColNVARCHAR_2 
    , T1.ColSMALLDATETIME_1
    , T1.ColDECIMAL_1
    , T1.ColDECIMAL_1

    FROM TABLE2 T2
        JOIN TABLE3 T3
            ON T2.COLFKT3 = T3.Id
        AND T3.ReferenceDate = @RefDate
        AND T3.State != 'Deleted'
    JOIN TABLE4 T4
    ON T2.COLFKT4 = T4.Id AND T4.Name=@indicator
    JOIN TABLE1 T1
        ON T2.COLFKT1=T1.Id;

    RETURN;

END;
```

Essentially, I think it's a performance issue you're facing. Here's a simplified view of what happens: SQL Server "expands" the inline table value functions, pretty much like it would with a view. This way, you get 12 joins in a single query:

```
1. othertable
   join table2, table3, table4
   join table2, table3, table4
   join table2, table3, table4
   join table2, table3, table4
```

A table value function that isn't inline, however, stores its output in a form of temporary table that it returns to the caller, so it isn't expanded the same way.

```
1. (join table2, table3, table4) -> store in #temp1
2. (join table2, table3, table4) -> store in #temp2
3. (join table2, table3, table4) -> store in #temp3
4. (join table2, table3, table4) -> store in #temp4
5. join othertable, #temp1, #temp2, #temp3, #temp4
```

Here, the workload is split up into multiple elements. Some situations will benefit from an inline table-value function, whereas others (like yours) will suffer a performance penalty. It has to do with how many tables you're joining, the amount of data in each table, indexing, etc.

Comment: Your solution works OK, however I still not understand why the first TVF not works and I am very concerned because the same TVF is used in other queries and a lot of others inline TVFs were created to deal with similar situations. Is there any drawback of using non-inline TVF instead of inline TFV?

Comment: An inline TFV should have better performance than a non-inline, right? Using non-inline TFVs there are no statistics available for SQL Server to base a good execution plan on (btw I try to update my database statistics but it didn't improve the query execution with the inline TFV).

Comment: With that few rows returned from the function (a hundred or so, right?), statistics aren't really important. Do read the addition to my post - there's no such thing as "*always* better".